# Cookies' update from response delayed in future

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-cookies

I've encountered an odd issue with `ngCookies` service. Mainly, after receiving a response from my `/api/auth/login/` endpoint, with headers:

```
Set-Cookie  csrftoken=gxCld8gEga71MuQPQbjDujDBvR4HwPvu; expires=Sun, 28-Dec-2014 15:31:38 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
```

the `$cookies['csrftoken']` is updated after unspecified amount of time. This fact has been documented in the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies):

```
Only a simple Object is exposed and by adding or removing properties to/from this object, new cookies are created/deleted at the end of current $eval.
```

Knowing that, I've resorted to the use of `$timeout` to hopefully delay the evaluation of my code to *after* the aforementioned `$eval`.

Ended up with the following (CoffeeScript):

```
login = () ->
    deferred = $q.defer()

    $http.post('/api/accounts/login/', data)
    .success((data) ->
        args = arguments
        $timeout(() ->
            do_fancy_stuff()
            deferred.resolve.apply(deferred, args)
        )
        return
    ).error(() ->
        args = arguments
        $timeout(() ->
            deferred.reject.apply(deferred, args)
        )
        return
    )

    promise = deferred.promise
    promise.success = promise.then
    promise.error = promise.catch
    promise
```

But the code above still suffers from the issue. Cookies are updated with the value from response way after `$timeout` kicks in.

After adding `console.log('cookies push', $browser.cookies().csrftoken, cookies.csrftoken);` [here](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies/blob/v1.2.5/angular-cookies.js#L131) (after the `if` statement). I've ended up with something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the tokens were equal after 7 prints.

The `yhQqT6KOfSKYCNB3Ag4sEPllMgkLrVj1` token comes from previous session. I'm testing logging out and in to the app without refreshing the page. The `Setting X-CSRFToken` is called directly in my `do_fancy_stuff()` function (no async things, just bare `$cookies['csrftoken']` access).

Also the use of `$q` is required to provide `$http`-like promise as return value (there would be no `$q` if cookies were working fine).

Comment: I think I am experiencing a similar issue. Any progress on a resolution?

Comment: @SethM., I have actually made it so that my `login` views return `X-CSRFToken` header with the value of the token. With that, it's possible to directly set the default `$http` header in the response for upcoming requests. Note, that I claim this to be a hack rather than a solution.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I chose to use based on the information found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1bb33cccbe12bda4c397ddabab35ba1df85d5137/src/ng/browser.js#L102) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1bb33cccbe12bda4c397ddabab35ba1df85d5137/src/ngCookies/cookies.js#L58-L66). Tells me that the $cookies will attempt to refresh every 100ms. So with this information in mind you can add a $timeout to any request that needs to use the response cookies.

```
        $http.post(url, tokens)
            .success(function(result, status, headers, config) { // sign in successful
                $timeout(function() { /* do stuff with $cookies here. */ }, 100);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$cookies` service has a `pollerfn` that copies all cookies from the `$browser`, and this poller periodically executes every 100ms.So better to put a `$timeout` for 150ms for avoiding the edge cases.